Use Collection of Pairs For Insert Statement?
I have a table with a compound primary key, and I want to do a bulk insert for all keys (data migration/staging).
Currently it looks like, if you pass a collection to a MyBatis insert, it expects all elements to be of the ResultMap type. Maybe I'm missing some plumbing in my config, but is it possible to get MyBatis to understand the Apache Commons Pair (or any other K/V structure, I'm not picky) as a collection element to make the following work?
Here's the insert from the mapper
<insert id="saveUsers">
        INSERT OR UPDATE INTO UserConfig(accountNumber,
        userId,
        role,
        ...)
        VALUES (
          <foreach item="entry" index="index" collection="accountUsers" separator=",">
             (#{entry.left, javaType=com.my.company.dataid.account.AccountNumber},
             #{entry.right.userId},
             #{entry.right.role},
             ...
             )
          </foreach>
        )
</insert>

Here is the Java interface for it
void saveUsers(@Param("accountUsers") final List<Pair<AccountNumber, User>> accountUsers);

Error from MyBatis
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'left' in 'class com.my.company.common.entity.User'
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.Reflector.getGetInvoker(Reflector.java:385)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaClass.getGetInvoker(MetaClass.java:160)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BeanWrapper.getBeanProperty(BeanWrapper.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BeanWrapper.get(BeanWrapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.getValue(MetaObject.java:115)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BaseWrapper.getChildValue(BaseWrapper.java:121)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.MapWrapper.get(MapWrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.getValue(MetaObject.java:115)
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.BoundSql.getAdditionalParameter(BoundSql.java:74)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.parameterize(PreparedStatementHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:65)


When the elements of collection is java.util.Map.Entry, MyBatis assigns the key of the Entry to index and the value to item. As Commons Lang3's Pair implements Map.Entry, in your <foreach>, the variable index is AccountNumber and entry is User. So, instead of #{entry.left}, you can write #{index} to reference AccountNumber. Similarly, instead of #{entry.right.userId}, you can write #{entry.userId}.

@ave I will give that a try later today. QQ: but I have multiple entries with the same accountNumber. Is that an issue at all?

@ave That seems to have worked even when multiple of the Map.Entry items have the same key. But I DID have to manually set up the index+item approach.

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but you can, for example, pass Map<AccountNumber, List<User>> to the mapper method and nest <foreach> loops (i.e. use the outside loop to iterate the map's entries and the inner loop to iterate the list of users). It might be obvious, but the key->index, value->item rule is also applied when the collection is a map.

Ah, you need to specify the variable names for index and item if that is what you mean. There is no "default" variable names. I apologize if my comment implied that.

Not a problem. From what I can tell, this isn't plainly spelled out in the mybatis documentation on their website. Maybe over Christmas I'll put up a PR to help make that clearer for the next people to come along.

It is mentioned in the NOTE of this section, but improvements are always welcome

Credit to @ave in the comments above.
In my case, I had to explicitly set up the index and item bits of the foreach
<foreach collection="accountUsers" index="index" item="item" separator=",">
(#{index, javaType=com.my.company.dataid.account.AccountNumber},
        #{item.userId},
        #{item.role},

And then List<Pair<X,Y>>> works.
